# In Grails, I cannot override the default error message

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-validation

```
class User {
     String userName
     static constraints = {
        userName nullable:false
     }
}

*** I tried the different combination of the following in the message.properties ***
User.userName.null.message=The User Name cannot be null/blank
User.userName.null=The User Name cannot be null/blank
[package].User.userName.null.message=The User Name cannot be null/blank 
[package].User.userName.null=The User Name cannot be null/blank
```

But still no luck. I still receving the default error message which is "Property[userName] of clas[package_name] cannot be null. I'm using Grails 3.0.8

Comment: I also tried userName blank:false in static constraints...but same result

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be `User.userName.nullable=The User Name cannot be null/blank`

Comment: Thank You. It's working. It should be user.userName.nullable=The User Name cannot be null/blank .

Comment: Cool. Then maybe you should provide an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `user.userName.nullable`. Use the following entry in your resource bundle.

```
user.userName.nullable=Your custom text
```